# Exclude a tr from parents('tr')

Tags: jquery, html-table, bootstrap-4

I have an editable table:

```js
    $('.table-salva').click(function() {
                $(this).parents('tr').attr("contenteditable", "false");
            });

    $('.table-modifica').click(function() {
                $(this).parents('tr').attr("contenteditable", "true");
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-editable">
    <table id="table" class="tabella text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr class="hide">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Entrata</th>
                <th>Uscita</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>AAAA-MM-GG</td>
                <td>00:00</td>
                <td>00:00</td>
                <td id="bottoni">
                    <span class="table-salva"><button disabled type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">Salva</button></span>
                    <span class="table-modifica"><button disabled type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">Modifica</button></span>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>   
    </table>
</div>
```

In the table, when a user click the button "Modifica" thy can edit fields and press "Salva" to save (yeah, the buttons are disabled but after they won't). 
I want that user can't edit the field "ID", how can I modify parents('tr') to exclude first of td?

EDIT: I have another question. When user click on "Modifica" he can edit value of buttons too. How can I block buttons' value editing?

Answer (score 0):

I also suspect you don't want the buttons editable either

You could make the applicable `<td>`s the target using:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().not(':first').attr(...
```